Getting "ora-01481: invalid number format model" while comparing date in procedure
I have a query where I am comparing two dates to fetch data. Below is the query for the same:
SELECT CIRCLE, MPNAME AS ITEM,
  ROUND(SUM(INTER_FSA_UG),2) INTER_UG, ROUND(SUM(INTER_FSA_AERIAL),2) INTER_AR,
  ROUND(SUM(INTRA_FSA_UG),2) INTRA_UG, ROUND(SUM(INTRA_FSA_AERIAL),2) INTRA_AR,
  ROUND(SUM(ENTER_FSA_UG),2) ENTER_UG, ROUND(SUM(ENTER_FSA_AERIAL),2) ENTER_AR
   FROM (
   SELECT CIRCLE, MAINTENANCEZONENAME AS MPNAME,  
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'INTERCITY' then NE_LENGTH else 0 end )as INTER_NE_LENGTH ,
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'INTRACITY' then NE_LENGTH else 0 end )as INTRA_NE_LENGTH,
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'ENTERPRISE' then NE_LENGTH else 0 end )as ENTER_NE_LENGTH,
     
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'INTERCITY' then FSA_UG else 0 end )as INTER_FSA_UG,
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'INTRACITY' then FSA_UG else 0 end )as INTRA_FSA_UG,
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'ENTERPRISE' then FSA_UG else 0 end )as ENTER_FSA_UG,
     
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'INTERCITY' then FSA_AERIAL else 0 end )as INTER_FSA_AERIAL,
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'INTRACITY' then FSA_AERIAL else 0 end )as INTRA_FSA_AERIAL,
      SUM(case when SPAN_TYPE= 'ENTERPRISE' then FSA_AERIAL else 0 end )as ENTER_FSA_AERIAL
      FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_SIGN_OFF_SHEET_H
      WHERE
      UPPER(CIRCLE) = UPPER(STATENAME) 
      --HOTOOFFERDATE >= TO_DATE('11'||PHOTODATE,'DDMMYYYY')  TO_DATE('11-04-23','DD-MM-YY');
      AND TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(HOTOOFFERDATE,'DD-MM-YY, HH:MI:SS') ,'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(PHOTODATE,'MMYYYY')  // here is the error
      GROUP BY CIRCLE, MAINTENANCEZONENAME, SPAN_TYPE
      ORDER BY MAINTENANCEZONENAME
      ) GROUP BY CIRCLE, MPNAME ORDER BY MPNAME;

Note My HOTOOFFERDATE is DATE datatype and PHOTODATE is NVARCHAR2.
What causes the error and how can I fix it?

"HOTOOFFERDATE is DATE" - so do not call to_date() for that;"PHOTODATE is NVARCHAR2" - so do call to_date() for that.


My HOTOOFFERDATE is DATE datatype and PHOTODATE is NVARCHAR2.

You are currently doing:
AND TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(HOTOOFFERDATE,'DD-MM-YY, HH:MI:SS') ,'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(PHOTODATE,'MMYYYY')

The TO_DATE(HOTOOFFERDATE...) part will have to implicitly convert that DATE to a string, using your current NLS settings, which is fragile and pointless, so don't do that.
The TO_CHAR(PHOTODATE,'MMYYYY') is passed a string so it defaults to the numeric version of the to_char() function - hence the error you get. You need to convert it to a DATE.
If you want to search for a whole month range based on a passed-in date then keep the column value and a date and turn the string into a range, by converting the string to a date and then using trunc() to truncate that back to midnight on the first day of that month:
AND HOTOOFFERDATE >= TRUNC(TO_DATE(PHOTODATE,'MMYYYY'), 'MM')
AND HOTOOFFERDATE < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(PHOTODATE,'MMYYYY'), 'MM'), 1)

or
AND HOTOOFFERDATE >= TRUNC(TO_DATE(PHOTODATE,'MMYYYY'), 'MM')
AND HOTOOFFERDATE < TRUNC(TO_DATE(PHOTODATE,'MMYYYY'), 'MM') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH

Either way any dates that are at or after midnight on the first day of that month, and before midnight on the forst day of the following month, with match.
I've assumed your string actually has format MMYYYY. If it doesn't then use a format model that matches the actual string.
Based on your deleted question yesterday with values like '15-11-24 12:53:14' (with 2-digit years and 24-hour clock, not AM/PM markers) you might want:
TO_DATE(PHOTODATE, 'DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS')

Or change your process/data to have PHOTODATE as a DATE so it doesn't need to be converted at all.

Try
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HOTOOFFERDATE,'DD-MM-YY, HH:MI:SS') ,'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PHOTODATE,'DD-MM-YY'),'MMYYYY')

Why do you convert a string into a DATE and then back again into a string?
